# How to replace <NA> value for a particular column?

Tags: r, factors

I want to replace a value in a column whose rows are empty with "NO" for my column tech.role.

```
mental.health$tech.role <- as.factor(mental.health$tech.role)
levels(mental.health$tech.role)<-c("No","Yes")
Error in `levels<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, value = c("No", "Yes")) : 
  number of levels differs
```

This is the error I'm getting

Comment: Please use the `dput` function to add a [mcve]  (emphasis on the minimal) of your `mental.health` dataframe to the question. That will help us figure out what the problem is and give you helpful answers

Answer (score 2):

```
mental.health$tech.role[is.na(mental.health$tech.role)] <- 'NO'
```